# Converting string into int to find a result in java android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, calculator, calculation

how to convert some character like this `+`,`-`,`/`,`*`, from `String` into an `int`,
i try to find some result using `int`, but this character `+`,`-`,`/`,`*` make it error,
when i am trying to convert from `String` into `int`,

normally when you type `int i = 12+12` it will display the result of `24`,
but when i am trying to convert it from `String` to `int`, my app force close, any advice?, thank you

Comment: "12+12" in string format ...convert into 24  ..this's what you want, right?

Comment: You should convert the numbers separately, instead of converting the whole string..

Comment: The string "1+2" i.e. can not be converted to a number, because it must be all numbers.

Comment: @User9211 yes sir, i try to do that, but failed, any advice about how to do that?

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far..

Comment: @Lal,

`equal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String getTextView = textView.getText().toString();
                int result = Integer.parseInt(getTextView);
                String intToString = String.valueOf(result);
                textView.setText(intToString);
            }
        });`

Comment: Instead of `Integer.parseInt(getTextView);` , you will have to first extract the numbers from the string obtained from the textview and then convert them to integer separately and then do the arithmetic operation.

Comment: @Lal any simple example for me sir?, i have no clue how to do that, i am still new on programing, thank you

Comment: @WahyuRamadhan Look at my answer...that should work for you..tell me then?

Comment: @WahyuRamadhan I've added that as my answer..It is just simple..no extra dependencies are to be added. You can just do it directly..

Comment: @WahyuRamadhan did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Integer.parseInt(getTextView);` , you will have to first extract the numbers from the string obtained from the `TextView` and then convert them to integer separately and then do the arithmetic operation.

Do it as below.

```
equal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override             
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String getTextView = textView.getText().toString();
        String[] numbers = getTextView.split("+");
        int value = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]) + Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);
        textView.setText(value);  
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Replace

```
String[] numbers = getTextView.split("+");
```

With

```
String[] numbers = getTextView.split("\\+");
```

to prevent the dangling metacharacter error.

Comment: it give me error, "Dangling metacharacter" on the "+", and still force close

Comment: Please check the updated answer.

Comment: finally it's work, after convert last`int` back to `String`, for displaying output on textView, thank you so much sir, i appreciate that

Answer (score 1):

Easy approach should be using ScriptEngine Library -

Go to build.gradle(Module:app).
Add this dependency - `implementation 'io.apisense:rhino-android:1.0'`

Then To calculate value of any string, do this -

Use same code for all operation(`+`  `-`  `*` `\` `%`), just change the string value.

```
    String s = "12+12";
    ScriptEngine scriptEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("rhino");
    try {
        Object result = scriptEngine.eval(s);
        System.out.println("Result: "+result); // Result(Output) is: 24
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Example -
When user enters in EditText `12+12` take it into a `String s = editText.getText().toString()`

Call a method - `String result = calculateResult(s);`

The method is -

```
private String calculateResult(String s) {
        ScriptEngine scriptEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("rhino");
        Object result = null;
        try {
            result = scriptEngine.eval(s);
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result.toString();   // returns 24
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it as follows:

```
// Split the string from textView on '+'. In order to specify optional space before/after '+', use \\s*
String[] nums = textView.getText().toString().split("\\s*\\+\\s*");

// Parse each number into an integer, add them and then set the result into textView
textView.setText(Integer.parseInt(nums[0]) + Integer.parseInt(nums[1]));
```